# How to apply np.ceil to a structured numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, ceil, structured-array

I'm trying to use the np.ceil function on a structrued numpy array, but all I get is the error message:

```py
TypeError: ufunc 'ceil' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Here's a simply example of what that array would look like:

```py
arr = np.array([(1.4,2.3), (3.2,4.1)], dtype=[("x", "<f8"), ("y", "<f8")])
```

When I try

```py
np.ceil(arr)
```

I get the above mentioned error. When I just use one column, it works:

```py
In [77]: np.ceil(arr["x"])
Out[77]: array([ 2.,  4.])
```

But I need to get the entire array. Is there any way other than going column by column, or not using structured arrays all together?

Comment: remove the structure, ceil it, then coerce it back into the structure?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty solution based on viewing the array without its structure, taking the ceiling, and then converting it back to a structured array.

```
# sample array
arr = np.array([(1.4,2.3), (3.2,4.1)], dtype = [("x", "<f8"), ("y", "<f8")])
# remove struct and take the ceiling
arr1 = np.ceil(arr.view((float, len(arr.dtype.names))))
# coerce it back into the struct
arr = np.array(list(tuple(t) for t in arr1), dtype = arr.dtype)
# kill the intermediate copy
del arr1
```

and here it is as an unreadable one-liner but without assigning the intermediate copy `arr1`

```
arr = np.array(
    list(tuple(t) for t in np.ceil(arr.view((float, len(arr.dtype.names))))),
    dtype = arr.dtype
              )

# array([(2., 3.), (4., 5.)], dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

I don't claim this is a great solution, but it should help you move on with your project until something better is proposed

Comment: `recfunctions` has new functions to convert structured to unstructured and back.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a non-dirty solution, but I guess if that's the only way, than so be it. Thanks anyway, you saved me a lot of time googeling how to convert back and forth!